What is known about the generalization of non-linear Autoencoders?
Generalization is defined as the “model's ability to adapt properly to new, previously unseen data, drawn from the same distribution as the one used to create the model.” The model learns patterns from the historical data that is used to train a machine learning algorithm.
What are existing results on the generalization of the autoencoders or its variations? I am interested in knowing the generalization in principles. Are there any theorem or lemma which states the generalization of the autoencoders?
The generalization for linear case is known with some assumptions link. The error
$$\epsilon(x) = ||x-ABx||^2$$
Where $A$ is the encoder mapping and $B$ is the decoder mapping.
What is known in the non-linear case?

why would autoencoders be different from any other regression model?

@DikranMarsupial Marsupial Thanks for the comment. The structure (network architecture) of autoencoder is different as compared to the other regression models.

I'm not sure how the architecture is different from any other multi-output NN regression model.  In terms of the internal representation in the bottleneck layer it is difficult to define generalisation as there is no ground truth target representation.

@ Dikran Marsupial. Assume that target representation is equal to the given input. In other words $y_i=x_i, \forall i$.

I know how autoencoders work.  They are regression models where the target is the same as the input, normally with a bottleneck layer.  But they are regression models (and there is no correct ground truth values for the bottleneck layer, just the output layer).

@  Dikran Marsupial What if correct ground truth values of the bottleneck layer is known? Under this assumption what is known?

if ground truth were known, there would be no point using an autoenoder, you could just train a regression model directly on the ground truth for the bottleneck layer (and vice versa).
